# Docker on VM using loopback storage

Tags: docker

I am planning to deploy a few apache docker containers and a nginx-proxy container on a vsphere virtual machine.

I understand that the loopback storage device is not recommended for docker, but does it really have a huge impact when the server is a vm itself, with no dedicated physical devices?